# When will Azure Functions support AD MSAL 3.0 authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal

I'm using MSAL for Azure AD login and Key Vault authentication, but can't authenticate my Azure Functions.

When will Azure Functions support AD MSAL 3.0 authentication?

Comment: if you feel my answer is helpful you could mark it as answer to help others Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you know  [AD MSAL 3.0](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-3-released#plans-for-deprecation-in-msalnet-3x-and-msalnet-4x) Just released . When the azure function can be authorized with the latest library it not sure at this moment. Currently we are taking feedback regarding the features. Hope function authentication feature would be integrated very soon.

> **Note:** If you have any feedback you could put that [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/933). Your
>   feedback will be appreciated. Thank you and happy coding!

Comment: MSAL 3.0.8 is RTM, not in preview.  Released last week.  See https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/

Comment: Do you know when the MSAL 3.0.8 or above will support authenticating Azure Functions?

Comment: Okay I am updating you, Also will update my answer.

Comment: @Karl I had tried to get the latest update , unfortunately I cannot make it sure the exact assertion. Once I get any confirmation i will let you know. I have bit modified my answer also. by the way Thanks for your feedback on forum